# Regex: If theres more than one match I want to "discard" the whole match

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm pretty new to Regex so bear with me here. I want to match the string `{{body}}` but if it occurs more than once I don't want the expression to match anything. I will present an example and what I have tried so it's easier to explain what I'm trying to achieve.

**My Regex:** :

```
(?< !{{body}}){{body}}{1}(?!{{body}})
```

**Input string**:

```
{{body}}{{body}}
```

The result is no match as expected but if I change the input string to something like:

**Input string**:

```
{{body}}   foobar {{body}
# or
{{body}} foobar   {{body}}
```

I get a match on all the tags `{{body}}` and I want no match since `{{body}}` occurred more than once.

Comment: Which language/regex engine? `^(?:(?!{{body}}).)*{{body}}(?!.*{{body}})` will work in most languages, but better methods may be available.

Comment: What do you need to get in the end if the string is `0 {{body}} Text here`? A boolean value, a whole string or just `{{body}}`? What is the regex flavor?

Comment: If you don't want to match exactly 2 opening curly braces  body and 2 closing curly braces, perhaps you could use a negative lookahead `^(?!.*?(?<!{){{body}}(?!}).*(?<!{){{body}}(?!})).*?((?<!{){{body}}(?!}))` https://regex101.com/r/Chqvyi/1/

Comment: Or if possessive quantifiers are supported https://regex101.com/r/tqqp4C/1

Answer (score -1):

Using a nested assertion and an atomic group, it can quickly match a string
that has a single `{{body}}` tag that also does not have another in the string.

`(?s)^(?=(?>(.*?{{body}}))(?!.*{{body}})).+`

This can be seen working on a line basis  https://regex101.com/r/TtuMqA/1

Or, same but without the atomic group :

`(?s)^(?=(.*?{{body}}))\1(?!.*{{body}}).*`

https://regex101.com/r/dd3Kga/1